# how to draw image in opengl android

Tags: android, opengl-es, live-wallpaper, texture-mapping

i have to draw bitmap in to the my live wallpaper using this code but image will not loaded its showing null pointer exception.

```
public class Square {

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer; // buffer holding the vertices
    private float vertices[] = { -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // V1 - bottom left
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // V2 - top left
            1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // V3 - bottom right
            1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f // V4 - top right
    };

    private FloatBuffer textureBuffer; // buffer holding the texture coordinates
    private float texture[] = {
    // Mapping coordinates for the vertices
            0.0f, 1.0f, // top left (V2)
            0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left (V1)
            1.0f, 1.0f, // top right (V4)
            1.0f, 0.0f // bottom right (V3)
    };

    /** The texture pointer */
    int[] textures = new int[1];

    public Square() {

        // a float has 4 bytes so we allocate for each coordinate 4 bytes
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        // allocates the memory from the byte buffer
        vertexBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();

        // fill the vertexBuffer with the vertices
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);

        // set the cursor position to the beginning of the buffer
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        textureBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        textureBuffer.put(texture);
        textureBuffer.position(0);
    }

    /**
     * Load the texture for the square
     * 
     * @param gl
     * @param context
     */
    public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
        System.out.println("loaded");
        // // loading texture
         Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
         R.drawable.nehe);
//here is the problem when ever i command bitmap it will be working .with out command its //showing null pointer exception   
        // generate one texture pointer
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        // ...and bind it to our array
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        // create nearest filtered texture
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                GL10.GL_LINEAR);

        // Different possible texture parameters, e.g. GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                GL10.GL_REPEAT);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                GL10.GL_REPEAT);

        // Use Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from
        // our bitmap
         GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        // //
        // // // Clean up
         bitmap.recycle();
    }

    /** The draw method for the square with the GL context */
    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
        // System.out.println("draw");
        // bind the previously generated texture
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        // Point to our buffers
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        // Set the face rotation
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

        // Point to our vertex buffer
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

        // Draw the vertices as triangle strip
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);

        // Disable the client state before leaving
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }
}
```

this is my logcat output

```
10-14 11:43:43.118: WARN/dalvikvm(3050): threadid=8: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d868)
10-14 11:43:43.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3050): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 9
10-14 11:43:43.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3050): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-14 11:43:43.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at frankandrobot.glwallpapervideodemo.com.Square.loadGLTexture(Square.java:73)
10-14 11:43:43.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at frankandrobot.glwallpapervideodemo.com.VideoRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(VideoRenderer.java:77)
10-14 11:43:43.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at net.rbgrn.android.glwallpaperservice.GLThread.guardedRun(GLWallpaperService.java:664)
10-14 11:43:43.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3050):     at net.rbgrn.android.glwallpaperservice.GLThread.run(GLWallpaperService.java:538)
10-14 11:43:56.398: WARN/Email(1452): Exception detected: Read error: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
10-14 11:43:56.398: WARN/Email(1452): Last network activities:
10-14 11:43:56.398: WARN/Email(1452): * OK Gimap ready for requests from 115.111.177.222 g2if3342858pbc.293
10-14 11:43:56.398: WARN/Email(1452): 1 CAPABILITY
10-14 11:43:56.398: WARN/Email(1452): * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH
10-14 11:43:56.398: WARN/Email(1452): 1 OK Thats all she wrote! g2if3342858pbc.293
10-14 11:43:56.398: WARN/Email(1452): 2 ID ("name" "com.android.email" "os" "android" "os-version" "2.2; FRF91" "vendor" "nvidia" "x-android-device-model" "INB-10/n" "AGUID" "+TIbwSeLDHum85UXux4T+QJD51g=")
```

need some help to do this stuff.kindly guide me a easy way i'm new to android and opengl....

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the nehe.png (or jpg or whatever)  to res/raw instead and then use the following:

```
InputStream inStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.nehe);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream);
```

obviously replacing:

> Bitmap bitmap =
>   BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.nehe);

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us which line is numbered 73?

I guess that you didn't initialized `textures` variable (for example):

```
 int[] textures = new int[1];
```

Comment: thank u for your reply i have already added that one.line 73 is Bitmap loading.

Comment: now i added my hole code here.i call this class on live wallpaper service class.. like wise i call                square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and it was in the render class, not in the loadGLTexture. Was an error because the "Context context" is not properly defined/called everywhere else in the live wallpaper.
Verify that the renderer class has a context e.g:

```
...
Private Square square;
Private Context context;
```

for the renderer class also need to put in the renderer method something like:

```
public Myrenderer(Context context){

   this.context=context;
   square = new Square();
}
```

and for the wallpaper service something like:

```
renderer = new render(getBaseContext());
```

You can also define a setContext method to define the context from the wallpaper service:

```
renderer = new MyRenderer();
renderer.setContext(getBaseContext());
setRenderer(renderer);
```

a working code : https://github.com/GLWallpaperService/GLWallpaperService/pull/7